# Google Trends API npm quota exceeded

Tags: node.js, npm, fs, google-trends

I am using Google Trends API to get historical trends data. I am reading keywords from a CSV file and firing google trends query.
Here is the code

```
var googleTrends = require('google-trends-api');
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('merged.csv', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
        }
        data = data.toString().split("\n");
        recur(0, data);
});

function recur(index, data){
        if (index < data.length){
                var keyword = data[index].split(",")[0];
                console.log(keyword);
                googleTrends.trendData(keyword)
                .then(function(results){
                        console.log(results);
                        index = index+1;
                        recur(index, data);
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                        console.error('We have an error!', err);
                });
        }
}
```

I get this error many times in between

```
[ Error: Quota limit exceeded, try again later
      at parseJSON (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/google-trends-api/lib/resources/htmlParser.js:48:9)
      at /Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/google-trends-api/lib/utils/trendData.js:26:11
      at tryCatcher (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:504:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:561:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:685:18)
      at Async._drainQueue (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
      at Async._drainQueues (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/shubhamjindal/Development/domain-info/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
      at runCallback (timers.js:570:20)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:550:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:529:5) ]
```

Can someone suggest me some workaround this error?

Comment: Yes! read the documentation and don't exceed your quota

Comment: But the documentation says nothing about how to avoid quota error

Comment: I'm sure google states how often you are allowed to query their api

Comment: Can you tell me some other API, maybe Python which fetches data using google login. I know one using pytrends package in python but it's not working :P

Comment: Ahhhh. You don't get what a quota is!?! If you are querying a (free) api, they sometimes/almost always limit your access to it; so that you don't query in a for loop without respect to anything (e.g. network traffic). It doesn't matter which language you are using.